# Problem importing eps files with auto-pst-pdf

Tags: shell-escape, auto-pst-pdf

First post, so I hope I'm doing it right.

I use Windows 7, TexMaker, MikTex 2.9. TexMaker and MikTex are newly reinstalled, and that's where the problem started. It worked before, but not now.

I compile with

```
pdflatex --shell-escape --synctex=1 --interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I want to include an `.eps` file to use with `chemstyle`, that in turn uses `auto-pst-pdf`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[crop=off, runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-pdf}
\usepackage{ifplatform}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{preview}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
%\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{Chemdraw/BMIM.eps}
\end{document}
```

If I compile with `epstopdf` on (and `auto-pst-pdf` off) I get the image, but with `epstopdf` off and `auto-pst-pdf` on, I get an empty `*-autopp.ps` file, and the corresponding `*-autopp.log` file reads

> Package ifplatform Warning: 
>       shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

But shell escape IS enabled? I have also tried compiling with `--enable-write18` with the same result.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The ifplatform warning is harmless and normal (auto-pst-pdf calls latex without -shell-escape). The `\usepackage{pst-pdf}` is useless in your example, beside this is works fine for me with another eps.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Do you have an idea what might be the problem then? As mentioned before, it worked before I reinstalled MikTex. Is there some path that wasn't updated?

Comment: Check the log file for mentions of `\write18`. What does it say about this?

Comment: For those interested: I solved the problem. My tex-file was in a "wrong" folder: It has an automatic backup-function which makes it slightly unresponsive.